# PhpStorm Symfony 4 ContactType class not recognized

Tags: php, symfony, phpstorm, symfony4

I have a very annoying problem today. I'm on Macbook Pro, PhpStorm 2017.3.6.

I tried to create a simple Symfony 4 contact form but something goes wrong with PhpStorm, the class "Contact Type" isn't recognized at all. I already tried to:

- Clear and invalidate PhpStorm cache
- Clear Symfony cache
- Reboot the Macbook
- Updated PhpStorm to 2017.3.6

I also tried to create the formType with another names, like `TotoType` for example and it's working, so its only with `ContactType` that's not working.

I use git also, so maybe it's a "cache" problem somewhere or a PhpStorm related problem?

[image]

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Contact;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ContactType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('field_name')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            // uncomment if you want to bind to a class
            //'data_class' => Contact::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

I also noticed that PhpStorm highlighted few errors about my `Kernel.php` file like this screenshot, and I don't know if things are related or not:

[image]

The Kernel.php file:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Kernel\MicroKernelTrait;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel as BaseKernel;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollectionBuilder;

class Kernel extends BaseKernel
{
    use MicroKernelTrait;

    const CONFIG_EXTS = '.{php,xml,yaml,yml}';

    public function getCacheDir()
    {
        return $this->getProjectDir().'/var/cache/'.$this->environment;
    }

    public function getLogDir()
    {
        return $this->getProjectDir().'/var/log';
    }

    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $contents = require $this->getProjectDir().'/config/bundles.php';
        foreach ($contents as $class => $envs) {
            if (isset($envs['all']) || isset($envs[$this->environment])) {
                yield new $class();
            }
        }
    }

    protected function configureContainer(ContainerBuilder $container, LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $container->setParameter('container.autowiring.strict_mode', true);
        $container->setParameter('container.dumper.inline_class_loader', true);
        $confDir = $this->getProjectDir().'/config';

        $loader->load($confDir.'/{packages}/*'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, 'glob');
        $loader->load($confDir.'/{packages}/'.$this->environment.'/**/*'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, 'glob');
        $loader->load($confDir.'/{services}'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, 'glob');
        $loader->load($confDir.'/{services}_'.$this->environment.self::CONFIG_EXTS, 'glob');
    }

    protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollectionBuilder $routes)
    {
        $confDir = $this->getProjectDir().'/config';

        $routes->import($confDir.'/{routes}/*'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, '/', 'glob');
        $routes->import($confDir.'/{routes}/'.$this->environment.'/**/*'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, '/', 'glob');
        $routes->import($confDir.'/{routes}'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, '/', 'glob');
    }
}
```

Comment: How is it being called/created? Please don't use an image.

Comment: I tried both ways, using console: php bin/console make:form  and manualy: right-click->new PHP Class. Same result.  Sorry for the images, it was to show it visually. Will post only code next

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I also tried to create the formType with another names, like `TotoType` for example and it's working, so its only with `ContactType` that's not working.

Based on screenshot ... the whole `ContactType.php` file is treated as plain text .. so no wonders that IDE does not recognize that class.

You must have accidentally marked this file as Text. To undo:

- `Settings/Preferences | File Types`
- Locate `Text` file type entry in the top list
- Locate and remove offending pattern in the bottom list -- it will be `ContactType.php` or pretty similar.

---

> I also noticed that PhpStorm highlighted few errors about my `Kernel.php` file like this screenshot, and I don't know if things are related or not:

Not related to the first issue for sure -- must be something else.