# Why PhpStorm doesn't recognize User_model.php as a PHP file?

Tags: phpstorm

In PhpStorm the latest version (2018), so it was in version 2017 in the project, I have a file called `User_model.php` and PhpStorm does not recognize it as a PHP file, it recognizes it as a plain text file.

But it was not always so; I only recently noticed.

I realized that the problem is in the name of the file (`User_model.php`). Because as soon as I change the file names (for example, `Users_model.php`), the file is immediately recognized as a PHP file.

Is it (`User_model.php`) some reserved name and it cannot be used?

I didn't mark file as "Mark as Plain Text".

This problem is present in all projects in my PhpStorm.

Comment: **Always** add screenshots. It will simplify things a lot. But so far: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21281563/783119 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/22709627/783119 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/49439872/783119 -- same story/solution.

Comment: @LazyOne thank you! the second link helped

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happened to me with a single file that I initially created with the name `myfile` instead of `myfile.php`. I found help here:
[Wrong syntax highlighting for PHP file in PHPStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306182/wrong-syntax-highlighting-for-php-file-in-phpstorm)

Going into Preferences / Editor / File Types, I found `myfile` listed as a Registered Pattern in both the PHP Recognized File Type and the Text Recognized File Type. When I deleted both of these, `myfile.php` highlighted properly.

Comment: This is happening to me but I cannot find the file in File Types. And other solution?